# Drag and drop tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm looking for some sort of drag and drop jquery/angular/javascript plugin from which I can add dynamic tables .

Like I can add new tables by drag and drop . I came across dynamic tables where I can add dynamic rows and columns and sort them but here I want to add tables . i.e if initially I drop a table then it contains single row and column after which I can add more rows and columns. Also I can add contents to the table.

I searched but Could not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're conflating a few problems and hoping to find something that covers all your requirements.  You'll probably be best off using one of the drag and drop directives (you can google angular drag and drop or angular dragula) for the dragging and dropping of tables themselves and then can handle whatever interactions you want in the table within the elements that are being dragged/dropped.